# Why "threading" is unknown for visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I include `using System.Windows;` but threading still it doesn't exist in the namespace
?!

[image]

```
            using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
        using System.Data.SqlClient;
        using System.Configuration;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Net.Mail;
        using System.Net;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Timers;
        using Graduation_Project;




        namespace GP
        {
            public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
            {
                static int count = 0;
                static int timer = 600;
                protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {

                    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
                    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 600000); // 600000 Milliseconds
                    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick); 

                }
```

still have aproblem
[image]

Comment: Please put your code as a text, not as an image..

Comment: Your DLL reference might has been missing.

Comment: @F505 - Have you added reference to `WindowBase.dll` to your project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` is in `WindowsBase.dll` assembly. Make sure you have added reference to that assembly.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -

[image]

**UPDATE** -

`DispatcherTimer` is meant for `WPF and Silverlight apps`. It can't be used for asp.net project. Instead you should use [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class meant for web projects.

Comment: Oh sir, seriously i don't know how to do that:(

Comment: I'm sorry coz I'm new in asp.net :(

Comment: Check out the update in answer. I missed that you are referring to asp.net

Comment: I found this!! Thanks alot( soo happy :)) [Finding WindowsBase.dll](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmahugh/archive/2006/12/14/finding-windowsbase-dll.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

[`DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class belongs on [`System.Windows.Threading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace which it's belongs in *WindowsBase.dll*

Be sure you added the right assembly in your project. It is proably in `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0` folder..

[image]