# Multiple WindowsBase assemblies conflicting

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a day into playing with .NET so this is likely noob level 1.

I'm running into an error where

```
System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject' from assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.'
```

Judging by all [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163130/why-threading-is-unknown-for-visual-studio) (and [others](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ac723b5-61a0-4ebd-b764-32dba5bbc232/systemwindowsthreading-missing-i-have-only-quotformsquot?forum=Vsexpressvcs)) questions and answers, I should be including a reference of the WindowsBase.dll from

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
```

That's all well and good, and the build is successful. However, when I run the program it fails with above error and the output shows that WindowsBase is loading from

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.6\WindowsBase.dll'.
```

To confuse matters even more, when I check the properties of the reference I added (from Framework\v3.0), the source directory of that assembly is showing as

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.1.0\ref\netcoreapp2.1\WindowsBase.dll
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, being new (I'll use this excuse as opposed to being stupid), I didn't realise there was a difference between

When setting up this project I used .NET Core, as opposed to what I should have used was the .NET framework (under > Get Started > Console App).

[image: Project setup]

Anyone interested - https://medium.com/@mindfiresolutions.usa/difference-between-net-core-and-net-framework-c0588e734b99